# List available languages of an iOS app in swift

Tags: ios, swift

What is the easiest way to list available languages of an iOS app in Swift ?

Here is what I would like to do :

```
let availableLanguages: [String] = ?
let currentLanguage = Locale.current.languageCode

if !availableLanguages.contains(currentLanguage) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set("en", forKey: "AppleLanguage")
}
```

I would like to replace the "?" with the cleanest solution.

## Edit

By available, I mean Language for which the app has a Localizable.string

Comment: available how? does "available" mean that your app has localization for this language, or does it mean that apple has a code for language? or that user chose that language. Please clarify.

Comment: By available, I mean Language for which the app has a Localizable.string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your clarification, what you need is Bundle's localizations. Directly answering your question, you are looking for [`localizations`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1417415-localizations):

> A list of all the localizations contained in the bundle.

But you can simplify it with [`preferredLocalizations`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1413220-preferredlocalizations) from the bundle. And you don't really need to check current locale, that list is already ordered:

> The strings are ordered according to the user's language preferences and available localizations.

So top of the list is best match for current user locale:

```
let preferredLanguages = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations as [String]
guard preferredLanguages.count > 0 else {
   // no localizations case
   return
}

UserDefaults.standard.set(preferredLanguages[0], forKey: "AppleLanguage")
```

Also look at [preferredLocalizations(from:forPreferences:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1409418-preferredlocalizations) if you need more precise customizations

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to list all Localizable files that are included in the bundle you simply need to call:

```
Bundle.main.localizations
```

According to the docs in the swift source code it will return a:

> list of language names this bundle appears to be localized to

Answer (score 0):

At my current company, we need to support different locals for Canada and use an enum for that. Depending on where you need to access this enum, I would put it in some global object or a protocol class. Let me know if that makes sense if your new at IOS. What your doing may be easiest to understand, but has some draw backs.

this doc should clear everything up:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html

Comment: Did you try availableLanguages = Locale.preferredLanguages

Comment: @claude31 OP is vague on what the purpose of this list is, but if you want to support all available languages for an application, The Locale.preferredLanguages is only that: preferred languages. Not all

Comment: well, he can use `Locale.isoLanguageCodes` to get a list of all languages, but if you think question is vague, why are you jumping to custom enum as a solution?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have an other project with this enum solution. I would like to know if there is a more dynamic solution. With an enum I will have to modify this enum If I want to add an other language in my project, but I don't see other solutions.

Comment: @nelsonPARRILLA This is about as easy as it gets, but the enum solution may be better then you think. You don't need to modify it that often, and it doesn't affect the functionality of existing objects or classes using it. Thus, it follows the open-close principle of proper architecture.